# LDP for Marchenko Pastur with k/n tending to 0

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, large-deviations

I am interested in the determinant of $W = X * X'$, where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ is a matrix with each row drawn IID from some sub-Gaussian distribution on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. (I am aware of some universality results, so happy to also consider a "standard" Wishart matrix with parameter $k/n$). Edit: say e.g. that the diagonal of $W$ is all ones, and the off-diagonal are of order $1/\sqrt n$.

Question (**short**): is there an LDP for the empirical spectral distribution of $W$ to Marchenko-Pastur when $k  \approx \sqrt{n}$?

Question (**long**):
There is an argument by Ofer here https://mathoverflow.net/q/372456 that finds the expected determinant of $W$, if $k/n \to c$ for some constant $c \in (0,1)$. The idea is to use an LDP for the convergence of the empirical spectral distribution of Wishart to Marchenko-Pastur.

I am interested in the case of $k/n \to 0$, and in particular, the scaling $k \approx \sqrt{n}$. Letting $\lambda := k/n$, and $\mu(\lambda)$ denote the corresponding M-P law, it is easy to check
$$ \mathbb{E}_{X \sim \mu(k,n)}[\log x] \asymp -\lambda/2 + O(\lambda^2) $$
I would hope that this implies something like
$$ \mathbb{E}\det(W) = \exp(k \lambda + O(\lambda)) := exp(k^2/n + O(k/n))$$

But if $k/n \to 0$, the referenced LDP gives the trivial answer $\mathbb{E}\det(W) = o(k)$. Is there a more "quantitative" LDP known that allows me to take $k$ and $n$ jointly to $0$?

Comment: LDP = Large Deviation Principle.

Comment: Actually, the argument I gave in that question does not really need the LDP, only concentration, and the latter is known for in your setup (e.g. if entries satisfy log-sobolev, or are bounded).

Comment: For a true LDP, unfortunately not much is known for general entries when $k/n\to c$

Comment: For $k/n\to 0$, concentration is even better, so see my first comment.

Comment: You are asking many questions at once. 
In the regime $k/n\to 0$, the $k\times k$ matrix $W$ is very close to $kI_k$
and then it it not hard to check that $E det(W)\sim n^k$ (unless of course you meant somehow to normalize things differently - seems you did because you talk of convergence to MP.

Comment: Good point, I agree that only concentration is needed, not necessarily an LDP. 

As to your last comment (sorry for asking so many questions at once!), this is exactly what I hope to improve on. In my scaling, with very high probability, all the eigenvalues are between $1 \pm \sqrt{k/n}$. So there is a trivial bound on the determinant of e.g. $\exp(k^{3/2}/n^{1/2})$.  

The back-of-the-envelope calculation in my original post using Marchenko-Pasteur($k/n$) seems to suggest that the correct answer is $\exp(k^{2}/n)$. This is what I was confused how to capture

Comment: (which for my scaling would be an improvement of $\exp(n^{1/4})$ to $\exp(1)$, and reflects the fact that the log-eigenvalues should have some kind of CLT cancellations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For standard Gaussians, and with the matrix $W/n$,
the proof of the LDP given by Ben Arous-Guionnet adapts
to the Wishart setup. However, you will have different scalings and so the non-commutative entropy term (of exponential scaling $k^2$) will disappear, and the proof more or less trivializes.
If I did not make a stupid computational mistake, the large deviations will have speed $kn$ and rate function
$I(\mu)= \frac12 \int (x-\log x)  \mu(dx)$. You see that $I(\mu)=0$ iff $\mu=\delta_1$.